# Filtering rows and group by a column

Tags: sql, oracle

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1000 |
| 1 | B | 2000 |
| 1 | C | 3000 |
| 1 | D | 4000 |
| 1 | E | 5000 |
| 2 | A | 1000 |
| 2 | D | 4000 |
| 2 | E | 5000 |
| 3 | A | 1000 |
| 3 | B | 2000 |
| 3 | D | 4000 |
| 3 | E | 5000 |

I want to filter `C2` to value of `B`, but if the `B` doesn't exist so I need `C` and if the `C` doesn't exist so I need `D`

So the result will be as the following:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 2000 |
| 2 | D | 4000 |
| 3 | B | 2000 |

Comment: 1) Please post what you've tried. SO here to help you debug your code, not to write it for you. 2) Your tags are very confusing. Is this a SQL/Oracle problem or a JS/jQuery/Datatables problem?

Comment: it is oracle/sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RANK` analytic function (if you want to include duplicate rows if there are multiple `B` values for a `c1` group, otherwise use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function for a single row) and then filter to only include the first rank in each partition:

```sql
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c2) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  c2 IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (C1, C2, C3) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C', 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'D', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'A', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'D', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'E', 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'A', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'B', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'D', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'E', 5000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 2000 |
| 2 | D | 4000 |
| 3 | B | 2000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wge7GjvR)